# Using database connection in separate form

Tags: c#, database, connection

I have my main form which has a datagrid view connected to a database. Then I have a button that opens a separate form and I've got a few buttons etc on that secondary form.

I need to query the database from the secondary form but I'm not sure how to do that without creating a whole new connection, which I don't think I need since the program is already connected to the database. I'm just not sure how to reference the oleDB connection I made in that first form (I didn't code it in, I used the little arrow on the datagridview to connect it to the database using visual studio)

Now instead of creating that new connection, how do I reference the first connection made in the primary form?

Here is my code:

```
//parameterized update query
string updateCommandString = "UPDATE RoomsTable SET [Date Checked]=@checkedDate WHERE ID = @id";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\spreston\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\roomChecksProgram\roomChecksProgram\roomsBase.accdb"))
{

    using (OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        OleDbTransaction transaction = null;
        updateCommand.Connection = conn;
        updateCommand.Transaction = transaction;    
        updateCommand.CommandText = updateCommandString;
        updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkedDate", this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.roomID);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
            updateCommand.Transaction = transaction;
            updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch(OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where exactly do you declare that "first connection" ? is it in the code you posted here?

Comment: thats the thing. i dont know where to look for it in the code since I used the IDE to connect it to the database.

Comment: But i know its got to be somewhere since my datagridview displays the data from the database, so it made a connection somewhere

Comment: Look for the definition of the conn variable referenced in the code you posted.

Comment: ive never worked with databases before but ive gotten this far. All i need now is the connection and Ill be good...but I dont know where it was made

Comment: _a whole new connection_ - look up the ConnectionPool before you 'optimize' any further.

Answer (score 1):

From a design standpoint, you should consider making a data access layer for your forms to utilize. You can create methods to retrieve those Db results for you so you consolidate that code and separate it from your form functionality. It may be just a small project, but it's good practice and if it's a project you want to grow, you'll want it laid out to be extendable.

Something like

```
class SomethingDA {
   static DataTable GetMyStuff(your params) {
     // establish connection, get your results
   }
}
```

You can then call `SomethingDa.GetMyStuff()` to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using the "`Using`" statement, your connection is closed after this code is run. You don't in fact need the `conn.Close()` and `conn.Dispose()` statements. Using does that for you.

Your best bet is to open up the connection again.  It is generally a good practice to open and close connections as quickly as possible, although likely less important if your Access DB local.  This generally does not impact performance too much as the OLE DB driver behind the scene will pool the connection and keep it open for a period of time.

Comment: ah ok. Well, my biggest problem is the connection I need was created for me by the IDE. ive been looking through all this code full of globals and things ive never seen before trying to find the darn connection that was first opened so i can replace OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\spreston\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\roomChecksProgram\roomChecksProgram\roomsBase.accdb" with the connection that was already made